# Take text from one place to another with tag edit

Tags: c#, asp.net, text, webforms

So, i know my title is abit confusing, but i can explain my self and i hope someone can know what can i do here.

I have a website(web forms, asp.net 4.5), which i have build-ed to my friend, and i don't know how can i do something,

I need when someone clicks a button then the website read a text file, lets say something like that :

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(xmlplace + "\\AppSettings.xml");
            string place = xml.Element("Settings").Element("App").Attribute("Dir").Value.ToString();
            string temname = Template1.Text;
           HTMLTEXT.Text = File.ReadAllText(place + "/" + temname + ".html");
```

HTMLTEXT = a textbox in the website, where all the text file information go.

Now, this function works 100%. its perfect. but then my freind ask me to do something else..

he gave me this text :

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 

//this arena
Show only this
Show only this
//end Arena

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
```

and he wanted me to take all the texts from the file, but show only the //this arena text, where //this arena is the start and // end arena is the end of it.

I really have no idea how to use IO for this, or any other way. Any one have any idea?

BTW, if i didn't expline my self, please tell me so i can changed and try to explain better.

EDIT:

If you can also tell me how can i save the file back with the changes, it will be great, thanks.

TY very much, any-one who helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(File.ReadAllBytes(place + "/" + temname + ".html"));
HTMLTEXT.Text = text.Split(new string[] { "//this arena" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split(new string[] { "//end Arena" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
//after your edit you have to read the text again if you use asp.net web forms or keep the text in view state


string editedText = text.Split(new string[] { "//this arena" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0] + "//this arena" + HTMLTEXT.Text + "//end Arena" +  text.Split(new string[] { "//this arena" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split(new string[] { "//end Arena" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];

File.WriteAllText("Path", editedText, Encoding.UTF8);
```

I advice you to use xml and LINQ better

Comment: It shows nothing when i am trying to use this. it does not seems to have any erros, but nor any text shows in the web.

Comment: maybe the needed area in the text different you can change it for what you need , **//this arena** **//end Arena**

Comment: i have tryed with //this arena
Hey HGey
HERY

HERYE
ET


//end Arena      ----- and nothing shows up

Comment: WOW, works perfect!, if you can also help me with the save, it will be really good.

Comment: What do i mean by save : save the text into the arena with also the text that was not in the arena, i need to replace the text with the new one after i edit it in the text box.

Comment: I will expline so we wont get into discussions in the commands. i have a text right, in the text there info, like "Hey man, hello" and then comes //this arena so, after the text is showed up in the tesxbox, i edit him. then i need to save him back after i edited it, but i still need the "Hey man, hello" and what was before i pued it into the textbox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60772/discussion-between-alon-m-and-ahmed-salameh).